# Trillian Timestamps

Tags: macos, timestamp, trillian

I've been using Trillian for years on Windows and more recently OSX.

Recently I have noticed that on OSX the timestamps next to messages have disappeared. This is most noticeable when copy and pasting conversations. I am fairly certain that on Windows when copying conversations it copies the message timestamp as well.

I would dearly love to turn this on for OSX. Is there an option that I have missed?